# How to get Ipython irkernel to plot graphics inline?

Tags: r, rstudio, jupyter-notebook

Having problems to get an R-script to plot "inline" in Ipython (Jupyter) using the irkernel. The script runs fine but the graphics are displayed in a 'Quartz Windows' instead of inline. How can I change this behavior? 
Have tried running the same script in Rstudio and get similar but inconsistent behavior. In this case some graphs are displayed within Rstudio while others are displayed in 'Quartz'.

Environment is Jupyter latest, irkernel on OSX Yosemite

Comment: Welcome to SO! I run jupyter + IRKernel on OS X and have not had this issue. Can you paste the output of `capabilities()` into a code (i.e. indented) block in your question?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I have a similar problem with running IRKernel from mybinder.org (web-based). In this case, it does seem like graphics capabilities are off:

`
jpeg FALSE
png FALSE
tiff FALSE
tcltk TRUE
X11 FALSE 
aquaFALSE 
http/ftp TRUE 
sockets TRUE
libxml TRUE
fifo TRUE
cledit FALSE
iconv TRUE
NLS TRUE
profmem TRUE
cairo FALSE
ICU TRUE
long.double TRUE
libcurl TRUE
`

Comment: shld prbly be a new question @SlowLearner esp since the OP has abandoned ths one

Comment: @hrbrmstr I'll set up a new one

Comment: @hrbrmstr As requested, I [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805798/r-inline-plots-in-jupyter) a more generalized version of this question. Hope we can get to the bottom of this!