# R inline plots in Jupyter

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I am trying to run R in Jupyter through the [Binder](http://mybinder.org/) project interface, though the question may be more general. For instance it question may be related the [long-dormant one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821369/how-to-get-ipython-irkernel-to-plot-graphics-inline) about Jupyter on Mac OS. I have the r-essentials, r-rzmq and r-repr added through [conda](https://anaconda.org/r). IRKernel and IRDisplay are part of r-essentials. However, when I try to plot anything, there is no output. Indeed, it looks like there are no graphics output options. What am I missing here? There is no problem in python notebooks, but no luck with R.

```
capabilities()
jpeg FALSE
png FALSE
tiff FALSE
tcltk TRUE
X11 FALSE
aqua FALSE
http/ftp TRUE
sockets TRUE
libxml TRUE
fifo TRUE
cledit FALSE
iconv TRUE
NLS TRUE
profmem TRUE
cairo FALSE
ICU TRUE
long.double TRUE
libcurl TRUE
```

Comment: Ugh. Anaconda. Even if I were to supply some triage & answer it might not help as I avoid that in favor of homebrew (macOS is my primary OS and I could try to debug this on unix but it might take a bit). As an aside, Binder seems to be only good at displaying an animated loading screen.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so as @hrbrmstr points out 'Ugh. Anaconda'. I could get inline plotting [to work by using a Dockerfile](https://github.com/mikheyev/phage-lab/), and installing R using `apt-get` IRKernel via CRAN, as per official instructions:

```
# Set default CRAN repo
RUN echo 'options("repos"="http://cran.rstudio.com")' > .Rprofile

# Install IRkernel
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))" -e "devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')" -e "IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)"
```